# What's a comprehensive list of parts of an ItemsControl?

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp, windows-runtime

The UWP XAML [ItemsControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol?view=winrt-19041) is the basis for many complicated XAML classes, like [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview?view=winrt-19041) and [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview?view=winrt-19041).

The documentation [Item containers and templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/item-containers-templates) describes 2 key parts of these controls:

1. **Data template**
2. **Control template**

These parts combine to create the final view:

> Container controls (such as ListViewItem and GridViewItem) consist of two important parts that combine to create the final visuals shown for an item: the *data template* and the *control template*.

In practice, developers specify the data template by specifying a DataTemplate in `ListView.ItemTemplate` (or `GridView.`), and they can customize the control template by providing a Style (`TargetType="ListViewItem"`) to `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`.

Developers can also customize the `ListView.ItemsPanel` (which is an `ItemsStackPanel` by default), and the default `Template` for the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` contains a `ListViewItemPresenter`. The documentation for Item containers and templates mentions these, too.

That raises the question:

**When I add a ListView (or GridView or any ItemsControl) to my code, what am I actually adding?** What can I customize? How is my data displayed?

As far as I can determine, the ListView looks something like:

- `ListView`

  - Renders its `Template` which somehow renders:

    - `ItemsPanel`

      - Renders its `ItemsPanelTemplate` which is:

        - `ItemsStackPanel`

          - Renders, for each item:

            - `ListViewItem`

              - Renders its `Template`, which is:

                - `ListViewItemPresenter`

                  - Somehow renders:

                    - `ListView.ItemTemplate`

But this is unclear to me.

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Answer (score 0):

you can customize anything in xaml

under the hood, both `ListView` and `GridView` can be created by `ItemsControl`, but their default template have some customization built-in already.

if you want to understand when to use which, here is a page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/lists

your data will be set to the ItemsSource if using binding, for example

```
<ListView 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
>...
```

or you can set directly.

from your question, it sounds like you may not have understood the basis, so maybe reading this series will help you:

http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/

it's for wpf, but the fundamental is the same, you can apply it to UWP as well.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not exactly answer my question. I know how to bind Items or ItemsSource; instead I’m trying to understand all the different “layers” of a ListView (or an arbitrary ItemsControl). The docs you linked describe basic usage, but I’m looking for a thorough dive into the guts of a ListView—what renders what, and which parts are customizable? Thanks!

Comment: The Dr. WPF pages you linked (esp P is for Panel and L is for Lookless) talk about some of these concepts (presenters and styles for specific parts), but I was hoping for a more consolidated “list of everything.”

Comment: As @sowen mentioned in his answer, you could customize almost all the controls in XAML. You could go to the generic.xaml file which contains all the default styles for the controls. It should locate in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\ [Version] \Generic.  Find the style of the listview, you could see the complete layer of the listview and change it.(Do not change it in generic.xaml, copy and use it in the page you want )